# Python exe and cplex .dll

Tags: python, dll, exe, cplex

I used python to model and solve an optimization problem, and it works very well in `jupyter`.

I generated an exe. (using `pyinstaller <filename>.py`). It worked well... I put the `cplex dll` in the same folder as the `python exe`.

However, when I try to run my `exe`. I have this error

```
CPLEX runtime not found: please install CPLEX or solve this model on DOcplexcloud
[7896] Failed to execute script Overseas_RFQ
```

I don't understand why It doesn't find `cplex`, knowing that the `jupyter` code works very well.

I use `Docplex`

Does anyone have any suggestion to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Jupyter is setup to correctly find the CPLEX libraries while your command line is not. In general, you have to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable so that the Python interpreter can find the required CPLEX libraries. This environment variable must points to the directory in which the CPLEX Python API is requested. This directory is for example `COS_INSTALL_DIR\cplex\python\3.6\x64_win64` (where `COS_INSTALL_DIR` is the directory into which you installed CPLEX). Be sure to pick the right Python version in that path (if you don't use Python 3.6 you need to pick something else than in my example).

I am not exactly sure how this Python-to-exe thing works. If setting the Python path does not work, you can also try to set your `PATH` environment variable to contain the folder that contains the CPLEX Python DLL: `COS_INSTALL_DIR\cplex\python\3.6\x64_win64\cplex\_internal`